# Abstract class that implements Runnable into interface

Tags: java, multithreading, refactoring, sonarqube, future

How can I refactor an abstract class that implements Runnable into an interface?

```
import com.codahale.metrics.health.HealthCheck;

public abstract class ApplicationProcessor implements Runnable {

    public abstract HealthCheck getHealthCheck();
}
```

UPDATE: And also how can I remove the usage of a generic wildcard type for the future?

```
import io.dropwizard.lifecycle.Managed;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import com.codahale.metrics.health.HealthCheck;

public class ManagedBean extends HealthCheck implements Managed {

    private final String name;
    private final ManagedThreadPool threadPool;
    private final ApplicationProcessor processor;
    private Future<?> future; // HERE sonarqube complains..

    public ManagedBean( String name, ManagedThreadPool threadPool, ApplicationProcessor processor ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.threadPool = threadPool;
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        future = threadPool.submit( processor );
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        if ( !future.isDone() ) {
            future.cancel( true );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Result check() throws Exception {
        return processor.getHealthCheck().execute();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't "convert a class into an interface". You can assign a reference to a variable however.

Comment: You can maybe do `public interface ApplicationProcessor extends Runnable`   No clue how it would work though gotta look into it.  (Also you would need to extends and not implement as interfaces cannot implement)

Comment: Yep since I don't need to extend from anything else that works fine for me, thanks.

Comment: If this is triggered by a SonarQube rule, would you mind precising which one ? I don't understand why question is tagged with SonarQube here.

Comment: Yes it was marked as a violation of type blocker in sonarqube. It was complaining that the abstract class ApplicationProcessor had to be an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface ApplicationProcessor extends Runnable {
    // interface methods are by default public and abstract
    HealthCheck getHealthCheck();
}
```

As for 2nd part use

```
Future<Void> or just Future
```

Comment: Using Void I get "incompatible types: java.util.concurrent.Future<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.Future<java.lang.Void>". Just Future solved. Thanks

Comment: right, Future<Void> would go for a Callable<Void>, here you have a Runnable.